# How can I convert LDAP Timestamps in Libre Office to a date time format

Tags: openoffice-calc, date, ldap

If I query the directory, I get the following results.

> ldapsearch2.4 -x -b "dc=localhost,dc=com" "cn=auser" "+" | grep stamp
>   createTimestamp: 20100407122221Z
>   modifyTimestamp: 20100407122221Z
>   createTimestamp: 20100407122436Z
>   modifyTimestamp: 20111229151358Z

I am pulling the directory into an spread sheet so we can perform an audit on our list of users. The current date stamp is not simple to convert into a spread sheet understandable date time object.

This helped me understand how the actual date is stored but I still need a way to convert it.
http://www.novell.com/coolsolutions/qna/6668.html

> This will return Greenwich Mean Time (GMT) in the following format: yyyymmddhhmmssZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the following value in A2

> 20100407122436Z

I can use the formulae to convert into a date time object that Libre Office understands.

> =DATE(MID(A2,1,4),MID(A2,5,2),MID(A2,7,2)) + TIME(MID(A2,9,2),MID(A2,11,2),MID(A2,13,2))

Which is stored as [Libre office epoch](http://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Date_and_Time_Functions) floating point number

> 40275.5170833333

With date formatting on the result It shows up as

> 2010/04/07 12:24:36

I am not using the time zone information as I don't have users accross different time zones in the directory. You can pull the time zone using the following formulae

> =RIGHT(A2,1)

Now I can sort by date all the user information I pulled from LDAP.

Comment: Excellent. Ensure that the conversion cell supports the entire generalized time syntax as defined in [rfc4517](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4517.html#section-3.3.13).

Comment: @TerryGardner, the time syntax can be set by the format options proved by office. Libra Office simply stores it a long int, http://help.libreoffice.org/Common/Number_Format_Codes.